# Свободолюбивое или свободолюбивый пачули?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно: *свободолюбивое пачули* или *свободолюбивый пачули* и можно ли так говорить?

Answer (score 3):

Если судить по [статье в Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%87%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8), то это множественное число, так что "*свободолюбив**ые** пачули*".

С другой стороны, можно считать, что это *кустарник* (м.р.), тогда "*свободолюбив**ый***".  Можно также считать, что это *растение* (ср.р.), тогда "*свободолюбив**ое***".  Иными словами, говорите как нравится, Ваш собеседник вряд ли знает лучше Вас, а если и знает, то поправит...

Answer (score 2):

Лучше сказать: **свободолюбивый пачули**.

Пояснение:

В словаре указывается, что пачули - это  **склоняемое** существительное мн. числа: пачули - пачулей. Например: ГАЕВ. А здесь пачулями пахнет. Современному человеку вряд ли понравится запах пачулей.

В то же время название используется и как **несклоняемое** существительное, например: куст пачули, агротехника пачули. А несклоняемое существительное может иметь род, соответствующий общему названию: растение пачули, кустарник пачули.

По определению, пачули - травянистый тропический **кустарник**, поэтому **мужской род** предпочтительнее.

Comment: Вера, но ''растение'' среднего рода.

Comment: Но не дерево же, м.род более информативен.

Comment: Вы правы. Но я хочу сказать, что ср.р. тоже возможен в некоторых контекстах.

Comment: Да, возможен, ошибки не будет.

Answer (score 1):

В [Грамоте](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%87%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8&all=x) также написано, что это множественное число (кроме Википедии, отмеченной Виктором). Стало быть, основной вариант действительно "свободолюбивые пачули".

А вопрос был ещё и в том, можно ли так говорить. На мой взгляд, да, можно, поскольку выражение "свободолюбивое растение" вроде вполне употребительно и нормально звучит в разных контекстах, которые можно найти, загуглив это выражение (в кавычках, то есть вместе). А раз с родовым наименованием это прилагательное употребляется, стало быть можно его применять и к различным видам растений.